# Extract substring in excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell, string-concatenation

I need to find and extract substring in Excel cell using function, if possible without vba.

e.g. cell string "A:Red B:Blue C:Orange"
and I would like to get value of B which is "Blue"

Comment: One more alternative: `=@TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(A1,C1&":")," ")`

Answer (score 2):

Use FILTER and TEXTSPLIT:

```
=FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),C1&":",""),LEFT(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),1)=C1)
```

[image]

Comment: Sir not posting since you have clearly understood the way OP has wrote so the credit goes to you, i have tried this : `=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A1,":"," "),
FILTER(TAKE(x,,-1),TAKE(x,,1)=C1))`

Comment: Go ahead, it is different enough that it deserve an answer.

Comment: Oh Excel is really amazing, i tried another way, i dont know it will work in real for OP's query, but with screenshot of yours sir, this one as well : `=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1&" ",C1&":")," ")`

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A2,B2&":")," ",,,1)
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

The input parameter `match_end=1`(last input argument) of `TEXTBEFORE` ensures it works for the **lkKey** column value `C`, treating the end of the string as delimiter, otherwise it won't work for this case. No need to add an extra space at the end of the input to make it works.